# Deactivate a toggle to hide a popup menu in JS by clicking anywhere outside it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have 3 menus `home`,`Clinic` and `About`. If I click on `Clinic` then a Megamenu is showing up and if I again click on `Clinic` then the Megamenu is hidden.

I want to Megamenu to hide when you click anywhere on the webpage.
The problem is that it is only getting hidden when click on the `Clinic` menu option.

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
      <ul>
          @if($_SESSION['navbar_number'] == '1')
          <li class="menu_active" style="color:#fff;">
              
          @else
          <li>
              
          @endif
          
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url('/') }}">Home</a>
          </li>
          
          @if($_SESSION['navbar_number'] == '2')
          <li class="menu_active" style="color:#fff;">
              
          @else
          <li>
              
          @endif
          
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Clinic </a>
            <ul>
    
                <li style="padding-top:15px;">
                    <a href="#" style="color:#8E499A;">
                          Laser Skin Clinic
                    </a>
    
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/clinic_service/Laser Hair Removal-1') }}">Laser Hair Removal</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/clinic_service/Acne & Acne Scar-2') }}">Acne & Acne Scar</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                
                <li style="padding-top:15px;">
                    <a href="#" style="color:#8E499A;">
                          Anti Aging Clinic
                    </a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/clinic_service/Power Thread Lift with PRP-11') }}">Power Thread Lift with PRP</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/clinic_service/Botox-12') }}">Botox</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/clinic_service/Filler-13') }}">Filler</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    
                    <a href="#" style="color:#8E499A;">
                          Hair Regrowth Clinic
                    </a>
    
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/clinic_service/Laser Hair Regrowth-18') }}">Laser Hair Regrowth</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/clinic_service/PRP-32') }}">PRP</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    
                    <a href="#" style="color:#8E499A;">
                          Breast Enhancement Clinic
                    </a>
    
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/clinic_service/Laser Breast Enhancement-21') }}">Laser Breast Enhancement</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/clinic_service/Breast Lift by Radiofrequency-22') }}">Breast Lift by Radiofrequency</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            
            </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".menu > ul > li").click(function (e) {
        if ($(window).width() > 943) {
            $(this).children("ul").fadeToggle(150);
    //         e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

To deactivate the toggle and hide the menu, I have tried to use this:

```
$(window).click(function(e)
{
   if ($(window).width() > 943) {
        $(".menu > ul > li > ul").hide();
    }    
});
```

But when I use this, clicking on the `Clinic` menu option doesn't work any more.
How to solve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a click on the menu will trigger both `$(".menu > ul > li").click()` and `$(window).click()`. So even if it gets toggled on, its getting hidden again in `$(window).click()`

**You can change the `$(window).click` function to first check if the click was outside the menu, and only do something if it was.**

The code below checks the clicked element to see if it is a child of `.menu`, and if it is it does nothing. If the click wasn't on an element in the `.menu` element, then it will hide the menu.

```
$(window).click(function(e) {
    if ($(window).width() > 94) {
        // Check if .menu is an ancestor of the clicked element
        // If it is, then ignore the click because it's not outside the menu
        if (!$(e.target).closest('.menu').length) {
            $(".menu > ul > li > ul").hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Run this **working snippet** I made from your code to see it in action! (Note I've change your media query and the width of the menu so that you can see it working in the smaller snippet window).

```js
$(".menu > ul > li").click(function(e) {
    if ($(window).width() > 94) {
        $(this).children("ul").fadeToggle(150);
  }
});

$(window).click(function(e) {
    if ($(window).width() > 94) {
        // Check if .menu is an ancestor of the clicked element
        // If it is, then ignore the click because it's not outside the menu
        if (!$(e.target).closest('.menu').length) {
            $(".menu > ul > li > ul").hide();
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.menu {
  width: 300px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url('/') }}">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Clinic </a>
      <ul>

        <li style="padding-top:15px;">
          <a href="#" style="color:#8E499A;">
                          Laser Skin Clinic
                    </a>

          <ul>
            <li><a href="{{ url('/clinic_service/Laser Hair Removal-1') }}">Laser Hair Removal</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url('/clinic_service/Acne & Acne Scar-2') }}">Acne & Acne Scar</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li style="padding-top:15px;">
          <a href="#" style="color:#8E499A;">
                          Anti Aging Clinic
                    </a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="{{ url('/clinic_service/Power Thread Lift with PRP-11') }}">Power Thread Lift with PRP</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url('/clinic_service/Botox-12') }}">Botox</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url('/clinic_service/Filler-13') }}">Filler</a></li>
          </ul>

          <a href="#" style="color:#8E499A;">
                          Hair Regrowth Clinic
                    </a>

          <ul>
            <li><a href="{{ url('/clinic_service/Laser Hair Regrowth-18') }}">Laser Hair Regrowth</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url('/clinic_service/PRP-32') }}">PRP</a></li>
          </ul>

          <a href="#" style="color:#8E499A;">
                          Breast Enhancement Clinic
                    </a>

          <ul>
            <li><a href="{{ url('/clinic_service/Laser Breast Enhancement-21') }}">Laser Breast Enhancement</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url('/clinic_service/Breast Lift by Radiofrequency-22') }}">Breast Lift by Radiofrequency</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Another test option</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @ArafatRahman I’m not a bro, I’m female, but you’re welcome anyway! :)