# jQuery click toggle event, can't figure out how to have the first click on the div and second click anywhere EXCEPT the div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

the attached code allows you to click on a div to bring it into "focus" like a modal dialogue box, which is what I wanted it to do. However, I don't want to have to click on the div a second time to "dismiss" it, instead I want to click anywhere outside of the div.

I'm completely stumped at this point, and can't seem to find any good resources for it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
$('[id^=TestDiv]').click(function(e) {
  $('#TestDiv' + this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0]).toggleClass('fullscreen');
  $('#overlay').toggle();
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
}

#Container {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "myDiv1 myDiv2"
    "myDiv3 myDiv4";
}

div.fullscreen {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

#TestDiv1 {
  background: red;
  grid-area: myDiv1;
}

#TestDiv2 {
  background: green;
  grid-area: myDiv2;
}

#TestDiv3 {
  background: blue;
  grid-area: myDiv3;
}

#TestDiv4 {
  background: yellow;
  grid-area: myDiv4;
}

div[id^='TestDiv'] {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
}

span.text {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  font-size: 0.5em;
}

span.integer {
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-right: 4%;
  font-size: 0.55em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <div id="Container">
      <div id="TestDiv1" class="top">
        <div>
          <span class="text">text content </span>
          <span class="integer">1</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="TestDiv2" class="top">
        <div>
          <span class="text">text content </span>
          <span class="integer">2</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="TestDiv3" class="bottom">
        <div>
          <span class="text">text content </span>
          <span class="integer">3</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="TestDiv4" class="bottom">
        <div>
          <span class="text">text content </span>
          <span class="integer">4</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deactivate a toggle to hide a popup menu in JS by clicking anywhere outside it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62650097/deactivate-a-toggle-to-hide-a-popup-menu-in-js-by-clicking-anywhere-outside-it)

Answer (score 1):

You are using toggle class, the problem is that just use addClass, do the below code, it will work:

```
$('[id^=TestDiv]').click(function(e) {
    $('#TestDiv' + this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0]).addClass('fullscreen');
    $('#overlay').css("display","block");
});
$('#overlay').click(function () {
    $('[id^=TestDiv]').removeClass('fullscreen');
    $('#overlay').css("display","none");
});
```

```js
$('[id^=TestDiv]').click(function(e) {
        $('#TestDiv' + this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0]).addClass('fullscreen');
        $('#overlay').css("display","block");
    });
    $('#overlay').click(function () {
        $('[id^=TestDiv]').removeClass('fullscreen');
        $('#overlay').css("display","none");
    });
```

```css
body {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vh;
    }

    #Container {
        margin: auto;
        padding: 0;
        display: grid;
        background-color: black;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-areas:
                "myDiv1 myDiv2"
                "myDiv3 myDiv4";
    }

    div.fullscreen {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 9999;
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
    }

    #TestDiv1 {
        background: red;
        grid-area: myDiv1;
    }

    #TestDiv2 {
        background: green;
        grid-area: myDiv2;
    }

    #TestDiv3 {
        background: blue;
        grid-area: myDiv3;
    }

    #TestDiv4 {
        background: yellow;
        grid-area: myDiv4;
    }

    div[id^='TestDiv'] {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    span.text {
        float: left;
        margin-bottom: 2%;
        margin-left: 2%;
        font-size: 0.5em;
    }

    span.integer {
        float: right;
        margin-bottom: 2%;
        margin-right: 4%;
        font-size: 0.55em;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    #overlay {
        position: fixed;
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        z-index: 2;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="Container">
    <div id="TestDiv1" class="top">
        <div>
            <span class="text">text content </span>
            <span class="integer">1</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="TestDiv2" class="top">
        <div>
            <span class="text">text content </span>
            <span class="integer">2</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="TestDiv3" class="bottom">
        <div>
            <span class="text">text content </span>
            <span class="integer">3</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="TestDiv4" class="bottom">
        <div>
            <span class="text">text content </span>
            <span class="integer">4</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's my pleasure :)